# Everything is a singleton--requests aren't creating new scopes (ASP.NET Core 2.x inside .NET Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, webforms

We're migrating an extensive webforms application to the .NET 5+/.NET Core world. We've moved much of the back end library code to .NET Standard 2.0.

As an interim step to incrementally move over functionality, we've set up an ASP.NET Core 2.2 (last version that runs on .NET Standard 2.0) project that runs within the .NET Framework webforms application. This works quite well except for one fatal flaw we've encountered: **everything is the same scope, and so scoped objects are getting treated like singletons**. Among other problems, this means the application latches onto the first logged-in user it sees. Transients are working correctly, though.

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/PosInformatique/PosInformatique.AspNetCore.Server.AspNet/tree/master/AspNetCore.Server.AspNet) to properly route in the ASP.NET Core part of the app--without it everything comes back 404. But I'm not certain if the library is to blame or some other quirk of webforms.

**Where should I look in the ASP.NET Core 2.2 pipeline for where each HTTP request is supposed to get its own IServiceProvider scope created to fix this or do it manually?**

Comment: I think the best place to see how things like your routes etc work would be to start a fresh application from the template which gives some indication of how to set up routing etc.  HttpContext is available to most controllers for example.  Can you elaborate on your question? Like what do you mena by scopes as the word has many different means in context of an application.

Comment: @AliK I'm referring to IServiceProvider's scopes for dependency injection. Normally, the pipeline creates a new scope for each web request automatically in ASP.NET Core. This isn't happening here for whatever reason. Items that are registered in Startup.cs as .AddScoped() are being treated as if they were registered as .AddSingleton() because a new scope isn't being auto-created per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area I was looking for turns out to be the `RequestServicesContainerMiddleware`, which produces a new scope for each request. There's a check to see if an [`IServiceProvidersFeature` is already set](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/b6a3fee08869cd9ac9d266b15b4eb7de205199ed/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.cs#L42). The library I'm using [defines this up front](https://github.com/PosInformatique/PosInformatique.AspNetCore.Server.AspNet/blob/b390e325acac085e766ac753da6335a5353ffdd2/AspNetCore.Server.AspNet/AspNetServer.cs#L37).

The solution/workaround for now is that I've added in a simplified version of the `RequestServicesContainerMiddleware` that *always* creates a new service scope.

([This unrelated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38960122/826620) on how to modify the DI system helped tremendously.)