# Hierarchical scope after Dependency injection v. 8.0.0

Tags: c#, autofac

Ive been trying to upgrade to latest Autofac/Multitenant/Dependency injection.

Release 8.0.0 states that there is a breaking change:
https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/releases/tag/v8.0.0

> IServiceScopeFactory is now a singleton and child scopes are flat, not hierarchical.

Right now my Controllers fail when they try to resolve a dependency which is inside the "Parent lifetime scope", as the parent lifetime scope is just "root" now.

Previously the "Parent lifetime scope" was a "tenant lifetime" (as im using multitenant package) and then it worked.

I just cannot figure out how/where to apply the below "fix" in ASP.NET Core and have hierachical scopes as in previous versions.

I have copied the samples from here:
https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant/tree/develop/samples/Sandbox.AspNetCore5_To_6

and it works as expected (scopes are flat and resolved from root (not tenant-scope))

Where do I put this code to control the created scopes etc. ?

```
// Based on an IServiceProvider...
IServiceProvider provider = CreateServiceProvider();

// You'll need to get an Autofac lifetime scope.
var autofacScope = provider.GetService<ILifetimeScope>();

// Use the Autofac constructs to create hierarchical lifetimes.
var unitOfWorkOutside = autofacScope.BeginLifetimeScope();

// And later have a sub-unit-of-work scope inside that...
var unitOfWorkInside = unitOfWorkOutside.BeginLifetimeScope();

// Now they're related so they'll share a hierarchy. If you dispose the outer scope...
unitOfWorkOutside.Dispose();

// ...stuff in the inner scope will not resolve because you disposed its parent.
unitOfWorkInside.Resolve<MyService>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a hierarchical lifetime scope now, you need to get the current request scope and manually create it. This means either resolving `ILifetimeScope` from an `IServiceProvider` or injecting `ILifetimeScope` into your controller and resolve things using service location.

Here's getting it from the service provider:

```cs
public class MyController
{
  public IActionResult DoWork()
  {
    var requestScope = this.Context.RequestServices.GetService<ILifetimeScope>();
    using var unitOfWorkScope = this._requestScope.BeginLifetimeScope();
    var thing = unitOfWorkScope.Resolve<Thing>();
    return thing.DoWork();
  }
}
```

Here's injecting `ILifetimeScope` into the controller:

```cs
public class MyController
{
  private ILifetimeScope _requestScope;

  public MyController(ILifetimeScope requestScope)
  {
    this._requestScope = requestScope;
  }

  public IActionResult DoWork()
  {
    using var unitOfWorkScope = this._requestScope.BeginLifetimeScope();
    var thing = unitOfWorkScope.Resolve<Thing>();
    return thing.DoWork();
  }
}
```

In both cases, the request lifetime scope should be a child of the tenant scope. The only way to make a child of that child is to use Autofac directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I have tried to explain my issues in another "answer" - can you take a look? :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.
I actually think my problem is/was elsewhere, but trying to figure it out :)

Apparently my current code is outdated, i believe.
I can see the code has followed an other "guide" from you (from 2017):

[Autofac.Multitenant in an aspnet core application does not seem to resolve tenant scoped dependencies correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940241/autofac-multitenant-in-an-aspnet-core-application-does-not-seem-to-resolve-tenan/38960122#38960122)

This means that my current code does not use:

> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> services.**AddAutofacMultitenantRequestServices()**

or

> .UseServiceProviderFactory(new **AutofacMultitenantServiceProviderFactory**(MultitenantContainerSetup.ConfigureMultitenantCont

but instead follow the guide from 2017 with the "RequestMiddleware" etc.

> services.Insert(0, new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IStartupFilter), typeof(RequestStartupFilter), ServiceLifetime.Transient));

When following the code from the samples:
https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant/tree/develop/samples/Sandbox.AspNetCore5_To_6

Then the **AutofacMultitenantServiceProviderFactory** has code like:

```
        containerBuilder.Register(componentContext =>
            {
                var scope = componentContext.Resolve<MultitenantContainer>().GetCurrentTenantScope();
                var autofacChildLifetimeScopeServiceProviderFactory =
                    new AutofacChildLifetimeScopeServiceProviderFactory(scope);
                var adapter =
                    autofacChildLifetimeScopeServiceProviderFactory.CreateBuilder(new ServiceCollection());
                var serviceProvider =
                    autofacChildLifetimeScopeServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(adapter);
                var factory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
                return new MultitenantServiceScopeFactoryAdapter(factory);
            })
            .InstancePerTenant();
```

Maybe its this code that solves the tenant-scope issue?

Because if I just upgrade my application to use the newest packages, then **ParentLifetimeScope** will always be "root", but if using the samples then ParentLifetimeScope is "tenantLifetime" and then my "PerTenant" registrations can be resolved from ParentLifetimeScope

Does any of this makes sense? :)

Obviously I want to re-write my current code to use the new .NET 6 samples, but I too want to understand what the difference is

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow isn't a design review service or a threaded forum so iterative question/answer/question/answer/comment sorts of things don't work for this medium. Short version: You need to use the service factory and the latest samples due to the way ASP.NET Core has changed since the initial version.

You may be interested in [the Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you want the community to help with design and more iterative questions.

Comment: Thx :) I got the problem solved by changing my code to use the "AutofacMultitenantServiceProviderFactory" and "MultitenantServiceScopeFactoryAdapter" (as the samples show)